# Access Columns of Numpy Array? Errors Trying to Do by Transpose or by Column Access

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've a numpy.ndarray the columns of which I'd like to access.  I will be taking all columns after 8 and testing them for variance, removing the column if the variance/average is low.  In order to do this, I need access to the columns, preferably with Numpy.  By my current methods, I encounter errors or failure to transpose.

To mine these arrays, I am using the IOPro adapter, which gives a regular numpy.ndarray.

```
import iopro
import sys

adapter = iopro.text_adapter(sys.argv[1], parser='csv')
all_data = adapter[:]
z_matrix = adapter[range(8,len(all_data[0]))][1:3]

print type(z_matrix) #check type
print z_matrix # print array
print z_matrix.transpose() # attempt transpose (fails)
print z_matrix[:,0] # attempt access by column (fails)
```

Can someone explain what is happening?

The output is this:

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
[ (18.712, 64.903, -10.205, -1.346, 0.319, -0.654, 1.52398, 114.495, -75.2488, 1.52184, 111.31, 175.
408, 1.52256, 111.699, -128.141, 1.49227, 111.985, -138.173)
 (17.679, 48.015, -3.152, 0.848, 1.239, -0.3, 1.52975, 113.963, -50.0622, 1.52708, 112.335, -57.4621
, 1.52603, 111.685, -161.098, 1.49204, 113.406, -66.5854)]
[ (18.712, 64.903, -10.205, -1.346, 0.319, -0.654, 1.52398, 114.495, -75.2488, 1.52184, 111.31, 175.
408, 1.52256, 111.699, -128.141, 1.49227, 111.985, -138.173)
 (17.679, 48.015, -3.152, 0.848, 1.239, -0.3, 1.52975, 113.963, -50.0622, 1.52708, 112.335, -57.4621
, 1.52603, 111.685, -161.098, 1.49204, 113.406, -66.5854)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "z-matrix-filtering.py", line 11, in <module>
    print z_matrix[:,0]
IndexError: too many indices
```

What is going wrong?  Is there a better way to access the columns?  I will be reading all lines of a file, testing all columns from the 8th for significant variance, removing any columns that don't vary significantly, and then reprinting the result as a new CSV.

EDIT:
Based on responses, I have created the following very ugly and I think inane approach.

```
all_data = adapter[:]
z_matrix = []

for line in all_data:
    to_append = []
    for column in range(8,len(all_data.dtype)):
        to_append.append(line[column].astype(np.float16))
    z_matrix.append(to_append)

z_matrix = np.array(z_matrix)
```

The reason that the columns must be directly accessed is that there is a String inside the data.  If this string is not circumvented in some way, an error will be thrown about a void-array with object members using buffer error.
Is there a better solution?  This seems terrible, and it seems it will be inefficient for several gigabytes of data.

Comment: also, I suspected the error could be with IOPro, which is why I tested for type; however, when I tested the methods with np.recfromcsv(), I encountered the same problems.

Comment: Yes, it's not an error, per se, but it is the cause of your confusion. `recfromcsv` returns a [record array](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Recarray), which is nearly (but not quite) the same thing as a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html), as described by @Warren.

Comment: "...there is a String inside the data."  I don't see a string in the output of `print z_matrix`.  What does `print all_data.dtype` show?  (P.S.  You are using Continuum's commercial product IOPro.  Perhaps you could also ask them for technical support.)

Comment: Asking Continuum could help, but since I'm having the exact same problems with recfromcsv() I figured I'd try my luck here first.  And a solution has been fenagled!  I'm just positive it could be better and I want to better understand how to manipulate these arrays.

Dtype = [('Type', '<u8'), ('Num', '<u8'), ('Phi', '<f8'), ('Psi', '<f8'), ('SecStruc', '<u8'), ('Front', '<u8'), ('Back', '<u8'), ('Interacting', 'O'), ('CA-1', '<f8'), ('CA-2', '<f8'), ('CA-3', '<f8'), ('CA-CB-1', '<f8'), ('CA-CB-2', '<f8'), ('CA-CB-3', '<f8'), ('N-CA-CB-CG-1', '<f8'), ... (numerous more floats)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that the output of `print z_matrix` has the form

```
[ (18.712, 64.903, ..., -138.173)
  (17.679, 48.015, ..., -66.5854)]
```

That is, it is printed as a list of tuples.  That is the output you get when the array is a "structured array".  It is a one-dimensional array of structures.  Each "element" in the array has 18 fields.  The error occurs because you are trying to index a 1-D array as if it were 2-D; `z_matrix[:,0]` won't work.

Print the data type of the array to see the details.  E.g.

```
print z_matrix.dtype
```

That should show the names of the fields and their individual data types.

You can get one of the elements as, for example, `z_matrix[k]` (where `k` is an integer), or you can access a "column" (really a field of the structured array) as `z_matrix['name']` (change `'name'` to one of the fields in the dtype).

If the fields all have the same data type (which looks like the case here--each field has type `np.float64`), you can create a 2-D view of the data by reshaping the result of the `view` method.  For example:

```
z_2d = z_matrix.view(np.float64).reshape(-1, len(z_matrix.dtype.names))
```

Another way to get the data by column number rather than name is:

```
col = 8  # The column number (zero-based).
col_data = z_matrix[z_matrix.dtype.names[col]]
```

For more about structured arrays, see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html.

Comment: is there any way to access the columns by a number?  accessing them by name is in this case inconvenient as i will be processing dozens of z-matrices each with different fields.

Comment: I get an error of "cannot change datatype for object array."  I'm working on fixing it, but it is for this reason that I need to be able to access specific columns when converting the data and shaping the array.

Comment: I have added my deeply inelegant solution based off what you've written.  Do you know of a way to improve it, or is this what I'm going to be stuck with?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The display of `z_matrix` is consistent with it being shape `(2,)`, a 1d array of tuples.

```
np.array([np.array(a) for a in z_matrix])
```

produces a `(2,18)` 2d array.  You should be able to do your column tests on that.

Comment: ... the most elegant answer.  again.  and a void-array with object members using buffer error, again.

All of my data is numeric though, which just one string.  I'll be looking more carefully at the source of this void error.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to access numpy array. Here's a simple example which can be helpful

```
import numpy as n

A = n.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
print A 
>>> array([[1, 2, 3],
           [5, 6, 7]])

A.T                             // To obtain the transpose
>>> array([[1, 5],
           [2, 6],
           [3, 7]])

n.mean(A.T, axis = 1)          // To obtain column wise mean of array A
>>> array([ 3.,  4.,  5.])
```

I hope this will help you perform your transpose and column-wise operations