# numpy loadtxt not resulting in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Seem to be hitting a wall with a simple problem. I'm trying to read in an array in a file. The columns are a mix of integer and strings; only interested in columns 0,2,3.

```
import numpy as np
network = np.loadtxt('temp.biflows',skiprows=1, usecols=(0,2,3), delimiter = '\t', dtype=[('ts','i10'), ('sndr','|S14'), ('recr', '|S14')]) 
print network.shape
```

A sample of the input file; columns are separate by tabs `\t`:

```
1441087368  1441087365  186.251.68.208  186.251.68.145  17  137 137 3   0   150 0
1441087342  1441087341  125.144.214.126 125.144.195.105 17  137 137 2   0   100 0
1441087370  1441087370  186.251.139.178 170.85.175.203  17  35905   161 2   2   760 850
```

There are actually 30104 lines. The resulting shape of network is `network.shape = (30104,)`.  What I am look for is for network to be an array with shape `(30104,3)`.

FWIW my goal is to sort the lines based on the first column (a timestamp).

Any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated (as well as suggestions for how to do the sort).

Comment: for sorting, you could use a custom comparison key, e.g. `max(my_list, key=lambda x: x[0])` to access the first column. just adjust this to your data

Comment: With a complex dtype you get a structured array. The `3` you expect is the niumber of fields. Print a few rows to see that. `np.sort` lets you specify the sort fields.

Comment: Note that `'i10'` is not a valid type.  You'll get a warning in numpy 1.9 (and probably in older versions, too).

Comment: He's probably thinking of it as a fmt field width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a numpy array with shape (n, 3) where each column has a different type.  What you *can* create (and what you did when you used `loadtxt` with `dtype=[('ts','i10'), ('sndr','|S14'), ('recr', '|S14')]`) is create a *structured array*, where each element in the array is a structure composed of several fields.  In your case, you have three fields: one is an integer and two are strings.  The array created by `loadtxt` is a *one-dimensional array*.  Each element in the array is a structure with three fields.  You can access the fields (which you can interpret as "columns") as `network['ts']`, `network['sndr']` and `network['recr']`.

See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html for more information.  There is probably a lot of related information here on SO, too.  For example, [Access Columns of Numpy Array? Errors Trying to Do by Transpose or by Column Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849635/access-columns-of-numpy-array-errors-trying-to-do-by-transpose-or-by-column-acc/19849953#19849953)

Comment: and hpaulj.  Thanks, I tried to dig into all the bits across SO, but didn't see the issue associated with different types. I thought I had read that somewhere, but too inexperienced to make the connection to a structured array.  As mentioned by others, I'll sort with what I have and just write to a new file. Thanks for your patience.